Im a UG college student we have Maths lab in Last year and we are using mathematica but im getting error "cannot assign to raw object 1"
''' so im trying to get roots of f[x]=Cos[x] which is supposed to be 1.57068 but when i use the methord of constructing the function its giving me the error mentioned above
the code is as follows
  newton[f_,x0_,Nmax_,eps_]:=
  Module[{y0,x,x1,x0p},y0=x0;Print["f(x):=",f[x]];
   Print["f'(x):="f'[x]];For[i=1,i<=Nmax,i++,x1=N[x0-(f[x0]/f'[x0])];
    If[Abs[x1-x0]<eps,Return[x1],x0p=x0;x0=x1];
    Print["In "i,"th Number of iterations the approximation of root is :",x1"and estimated error is ",Abs[x1-x0]]];
    Print["The final Approximation of root is :",x1];
  Print["Estimated error is :",Abs[x1-x0]];Plot[f[x],{x,-1,3}]]

 f[x]:=Cos[x];
 newton[f,1,5,0.000001]

'''
can i please get a solution within 2 days ;-;

The problem is assigning to x0 inside the module. x0 is an argument. Add another module variable (say x0s for start). Right after you assign y0=x0, add the line x0s=x0. In the rest of the module, replace all occurrences of x0 with x0s. Finally, don't define f[x], when you call newton, call it with newton[Cos, 1, 5, 0.000001]

To be more specific, I mean this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/1871

You have many errors. But basically you were doing this
 x0 = x1

But x0 is an input argument. In Mathematica input arguments are passed by value, not by reference. So you can't assign anything to variable which is passed in to a function. Since then you will assigning to its value, which in this case happened to be raw object 1.  So you were doing this
 1 = .... something....

Which is not allowed.
You have to make a copy of it and assign to the copy.
I fixed few other things also
newton[f_[x_], x0_, Nmax_, eps_] := 
 Module[{y0, x1, x0p, i, x00 = x0},
  y0 = x00;
  Print["f(x):=", f[x]];
  Print["f'(x):=", f'[x]];
  For[i = 1, i <= Nmax, i++,
   x1 = N[x00 - (f[x00]/f'[x00])];
   If[Abs[x1 - x0] < eps,
    Return[x1, Module]
    ,
    x0p = x0;
    x00 = x1
    ];
   Print["In ", i, 
    " th Number of iterations the approximation of root is :", x1, 
    "and estimated error is ", Abs[x1 - x00]]
   ];
  Print["The final Approximation of root is :", x1];
  Print["Estimated error is :", Abs[x1 - x00]];
  Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 3}]
  ]

f[x_] := Cos[x]
newton[f[x], 1, 5, 0.000001]

gives

f(x):=Cos[x] f'(x):=-Sin[x] In 1 th Number of iterations the
approximation of root is :1.64209and estimated error is 0. In 2 th
Number of iterations the approximation of root is :1.57068and
estimated error is 0. In 3 th Number of iterations the approximation
of root is :1.5708and estimated error is 0. In 4 th Number of
iterations the approximation of root is :1.5708and estimated error is
0. In 5 th Number of iterations the approximation of root
is :1.5708and estimated error is 0. The final Approximation of root is
:1.5708 Estimated error is :0.


You should avoid using For in Mathematica, as there are much better ways to make loops like Do for example.
